# PHP Переменная с $_POST перед <input>

Tags: php, post

Можно ли создать переменную с операцией, которая будет идти лишь после переменной. Например, в HTML коде идет:

```
<input type="text" name="adminlogin">
```

А перед HTML кодом идет PHP:

```
$adminlogin = $_POST['adminlogin'];
```

То есть мне нужно, чтобы в переменную записывался value поля input, но чтобы в коде переменная стояла выше, чем сам html код.

Comment: Если это инпут в форме, делаете сабмит на эту же страницу, и тогда в посте уже будет значение. Только в `php` добавьте еще проверку есть ли в посте сейчас это значение.

Comment: непонятна суть вопроса
Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: @antonShchyrov Мне нужно, чтобы в переменную записывался `value` поля `input`, но чтобы в коде переменная стояла выше, чем сам html код.

Comment: @faik371 В приведенном коде `value` пустое. Ну так и сделайте `$myvar = ''`

Comment: Конечно можно, только значение в value писать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Порядок абсолютно не важен. Пока ты не введешь что-то в инпут и не засабмитишь форму - ничего в $_POST не появится

Comment: У меня стоит подключение к базе данных, которые вводятся в форму. Так как переменная стоит выше формы, то сначала идет подключение, а потом лишь переменная заполняется данными из формы. И выходит ошибка по подключению к бд

Comment: Причем тут БД, если у тебя сабмит формы и $_POST?

Comment: при том, что я с помощью $_POST ввожу и получаю данные для подключения к БД. Но так как переменная стоит перед вводом, то сначала создается переменная, которая должна быть = данным бд, и лишь потом идут инпуты, которые и передают их в переменную, которая создана до этого (именно поэтому она не получает данные)

Answer (score 0):

Можно и так, но есть ситуации, когда тебе нужно перекинуть на другую стрницуп ользователя, и там проверку делать, данные форм в сессиях сохраняют, и после первого отображения очищают. Почитай про данные форм в сессии, это очень удобно. А в этой ситуации делать проверку

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    // А после уже хтмл
```